# Database query error - [Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver]TCP/IP error, connection refused

Tags: jdbc, coldfusion

When visitors click a tab in our website an error screen appears.  The error says this:

> **Error Executing Database Query.**
>      [Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver]TCP/IP error, connection refused.
>
> ```
> The error occurred in D:/WWWRoot/deanlewisassociates.com/www/catalog.cfm: line 2
> 1 : <cfinclude template="Connections/dla.cfm">
> 2 : <cfquery name="menu" datasource=#MM_dla_DSN# username=#MM_dla_USERNAME# password=#MM_dla_PASSWORD#>
> 3 : SELECT * FROM products 
> 4 : </cfquery>
> ```

No one has changed anything pertaining the site, at least to the best of my knowledge.  How can we fix this?

This is the broken link:
http://www.deanlewisassociates.com/catalog.cfm

Comment: Internet says this driver is used for FoxPro database. Have you tried restarting this database(server)? Maybe something broke there.

Comment: My bad. I've got sql server on the brain. Still, the usual checks apply - can you connect to the database, without CF. Have firewall rules changed, etc..